# VB spread sheet writing lock

Tags: vb.net, interop, spreadsheet

at the moment I have a small application and need to take information from an object and display it into an excel file, using the Microsoft.office.interop class I've been able to write to the file, and it shows one by one the records being added, however about once every 3 times I try it, the spreadsheet stops filling somewhere between the 300th and 600th record, I have 6,000 in total and it's not breaking every time, I put a check after it finishes to see whether the last record is filled in but the code never reaches that point and I'm unsure of what's happening

I also don't know how to debug the problem as it'd mean going through 6,000 loops to check for it stopping... which might not even happen?

a little section of the code is here

```
loadExcel(incidents, WorkSheetName)
            If WorkSheetName.Cells(DBObject.HighestInci + 1, 6) Is Nothing Then

                MessageBox.Show("Failed to fill spreadsheet, Retrying now.")
                loadExcel(incidents, WorkSheetName)

            End If
```

above is the code calling and checking the method below

```
Private Sub loadExcel(ByVal incidents As List(Of Incident), ByRef WorkSheetName As Excel.Worksheet)

        Dim i = 2
        For Each inc As Incident In incidents

            WorkSheetName.Cells(i, 1) = inc.DateLogged
            WorkSheetName.Cells(i, 2) = inc.DateClosed
            WorkSheetName.Cells(i, 3) = Convert.ToString(inc.DateLogged).Substring(3, 2)
            i += 1
        Next

    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

*EDIT*

I'm thinking loading it to a buffer of some sort then writing once they have all been updated would be the way to go instead of it currently loading and writing each separately? however I have no idea where to start for that?

Comment: Have you checked your input data? Something wrong in `inc` var could be the potential source of the problem. Add a System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline(....) inside the incidents loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem, with what I had above Excel was opened and it started printing into the spreadsheet line by line, the problem is that any interactions with excel would cause the process to freeze

By adding an

```
ExcelApp.visible = false
```

before carrying out the process and an

```
ExcelApp.visible = true
```

afterwards, it all works and then opens the file afterwards